# In IIS 6, can one web site read an application-level variable from another web site? How about COM+?

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, com+

I have an IIS 6 web server with several web sites running. In one web site, there is ASP.NET code that sets an application variable using the simple syntax below.

Can another web site on that same server read the value that was set?

Can a COM+ application read that value?

```
Application("favoriteWebSite") = "I love StackOverFlow"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe so, but if these are web apps you could always make it accessible via a page that outputs the value or a web service that the other web sites could call.

Comment: Eric is correct your web site cannot read other web site's Application variable.